# Use a BooleanFilter in a AssociationField in EaseyAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

My entity Society has a relation in OneToMany with Client.

Class Society :

```php
/** @var Collection<int, Client> */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'society', targetEntity: Client::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    private Collection $clients;
```

class Client:

```php
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Society::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], inversedBy: 'clients')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    private ?Society $society = null;
```

In Client's class, I've got a boolean property `isSigned`. and I would like to put a BooleanFilter on it. If I use EntityFilter, I can only filter by the name of Client and If I try to do `BooleanFilter('client.IsSigned')` I've got an error.
Any idea to add a booleanFilter on my Association ?

Comment: There is an ongoing PR doing what you want to (nested property: `client.isSigned`, but it is not available right now. You could do your own filter that does what you want if it's urgent, but I would wait otherwise.

Comment: I can't wait but I'm willing to use it :) I will use a customFilter instead. If you have the link of the ongoing PR it would be nice. Thx

Comment: https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/pull/4882